# WCF exec while executing file or assembly System.ValueTuple or one of its dependencies

Tags: wcf, dll

Get error on exec WCF

```
 Exception through WCF, endpoint WCFEndpoint, while executing file or assembly System.ValueTuple or one of its dependencies
ERROR dial.Campaign.1.WCFEndpoint - [s13575s] [#188]: Exception through WCF, endpoint WCFEndpoint, while executing 'Dial(Tag=s13575s#client;To=5001;DetectionTypes=Nothing;DetectionTimeout=00:00:40;GreetingMsg=;SipHeaders(count)=0)':
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.RefreshFilters(LoggerFilterOptions filterOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory..ctor(IEnumerable`1 providers)
   at DotNetty.Common.Internal.Logging.InternalLoggerFactory.NewDefaultFactory(String name)
   at DotNetty.Common.Internal.Logging.InternalLoggerFactory.get_DefaultFactory()
   at ‪⁯‍⁪‍‏‭‏‍⁪‬⁭‫‏‌‏⁯‫​⁮​⁭⁮‫⁫‭⁫⁭‮‬‭⁫⁯⁯⁯⁫⁭‍⁪⁬‮..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Server stack trace: 
   at WcfExtensions.ExceptionMarshallingMessageInspector.System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply(Message& reply, Object correlationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableClientRuntime.AfterReceiveReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at WCF.IFlexSipDialerContract.PlaceCall(String callTag, String groupTag, ILineAddress from, ILineAddress to, DetectionTypes detectionTypes, TimeSpan timeout, String greetingMsgName, Dictionary`2 sipHeaders)
   at FS.WCFEndpoint.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Dial>b__1(IFlexSipDialerContractEx service)
   at FS.WCFEndpoint._PerformUsingChannel[TRes](Func`2 method, String methodDescription)
```

I added this DLL in the config like this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

but the error did not go away. What else can you do?

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Add this. Increased timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that the assembly you are referencing is inconsistent with what the program expects. There may be multiple versions of references in the program that the program cannot determine. You may try following steps to solve it:

First check if there are old references with different versions at runtime and delete them if exists.

Then remove the references and readd them with `Embed Interop Types = True`.

Hope it helps.